# Spring avoiding beans:beans and writing beans instead?

Tags: java, spring, jakarta-ee

This is working:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans:beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:beans="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context 
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.0.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/security
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/security/spring-security-3.0.xsd">

    <beans:bean id="test2" name="name" class="org.chicago.home.Test2"> </beans:bean>

    <beans:bean id="test1" class="org.chicago.home.Test1">
        <beans:constructor-arg ref="test2"/>
    </beans:bean>
</beans:beans>
```

This is not. But, I find this type of configuration better. What should I do to the namespace to make this below configuration work?

Also, can I pass idref in constructor-arg? That doesn't seem to work for me. Neither idref bean="" nor idref local="" inside constructor-arg is working.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:beans="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context 
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.0.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/security
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/security/spring-security-3.0.xsd">

    < I am pressing Ctrl + Space here, but it says beans doesn't have any child tags. 

</beans>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use something like:

```
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
```

Example [here](https://github.com/paukiatwee/webapp-boostrap/blob/master/src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/dispatcher-servlet.xml)

For inject constuctor, you can use:

```
<constructor-arg><ref bean="anotherExampleBean"/></constructor-arg>
```

[Spring documentation for inject constructor](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/2.0.x/reference/beans.html#beans-some-examples)

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you might have a typo in the second version.  I think this:

```
<beans:xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security"
```

should be this:

```
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security"
```

Unless you just copied it wrong.  If this doesn't fix it, can you post the error message?